# Do I have to let SimpleMembershipProvider (Entity) manage the custom user account?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

**Setup**

So I am attempting to use the new Simple Membership/role providers in ASP.net MVC (specifically 4.5) specifically through the WebMatrix.WebData.Websecurity.

I have utilized the providers ability to point the providers to my custom Users table.

I am also using NHibernate as my ORM of choice.

**Problem**

It appears to me that in the above setup, I would have to allow the Entity framework that the simple providers use to create user accounts, and be limited to loading (with NHibernate) the user account after created, to update it with additional data.

Is this correct?

**NOTE**

Yes, this question based on not trying to create custom providers based on either the simple or any of the .NET membership providers.